# Dereferencing NULL pointer warning in node generation

Tags: c, warnings

VS 2019 has tagged the following **c code** with a c6011 warning. The function is suppose to initialize an empty node for my doubly linked list "Client". Am I doing something wrong when initializing a new node?

```
//struct for my doubly linked list
typedef struct _client {
    char NAME[30];
    unsigned long PHONE;
    unsigned long ID;
    unsigned char CountryID;
    struct client *next;
    struct client *previous;
}client, *client_t;

//Function which creates a new node and returns a ptr to the node
client_t AddClientNode() 
{
    client_t ptr = (client_t)malloc(sizeof(client));
    //Warning C6011 Dereferencing NULL pointer 'ptr'. 
    ptr->next = NULL; 
    ptr->previous = NULL;
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: It is telling you that `ptr` *could* be NULL if malloc failed. Ideally you'd check to make sure it isn't before using it.

Comment: `struct client` is not defined anyplace.

Comment: So I should add in a parse for the malloc like if(ptr = (client_t)malloc(sizeof(client))) {//initialize struct pointers to null}? @chux My code runs without issue using the doubly linked list other than the warnings, client is defined as part of the typdef syntax above or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Zachary Martin Are you compiling in C or C++?

Comment: I'm using C, Sorry i forgot to mention it I'll make a note in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Retired Ninja's suggestion worked for my code. The ptr needed a check to make sure it wasn't null from malloc failing. The below code is the working function without the warning:

```
client_t AddClientNode() {
    client_t ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
    if (ptr)
    {
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr->previous = NULL;
        return ptr;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc Failed to Allocate Memory\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Note `(client_t)` not needed.  Consider `client_t ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);`

Comment: You are correct! I'll go ahead and modify it. Thank you!