# Dereferencing NULL pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to allocate memory for 2 float vectors with a length of 1024 and fill them with some numbers.
However, I get the warnings:

Dereferencing NULL pointer 'fpVec1',
Dereferencing NULL pointer 'fpVec2'

For the lines in the for loop. The execution is fine, but I don't understand the warning. Am I doing something wrong?

```
int main(void){
int iLength = 1024;
int i, j;
float *fpVec1, *fpVec2, *fpVec3, *fpVec4;
fpVec1 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));
fpVec2 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));
fpVec3 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));
fpVec4 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));

for (i = 0; i < iLength;i++)
{
    fpVec1[i] = ((float)i) + 1024.0;
    fpVec2[i] = ((float)i) * 1.7;
}}
```

Edit: I am using Intel C++ Compiler 19. The warning is generated in Visual Studio 2019 Professional Edition. The warning disappeared when I used an if statement as in the accepted solution, to check the validity of the pointers.

Comment: Which compiler/tool is giving this warning?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885461/dereferencing-null-pointer-warning-in-node-generation) if you actually check the resulting values of malloc() before actually using the pointers, the warning will go away.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including lines such as `#include <stdlib.h>`, the name and version of the compiler you are using, and the switches you are compiling with. If possible, also provide a link to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) that shows a reproduction of the problem. If the messages are coming from the IDE or some tool in it other than the compiler (e.g., they are displayed by the code editor, before the program is compiled), state that.

Comment: The post mmixLinus turned up shows the error code C6011. This is essential information you should have included in the post. Simply searching the web for “C6011” easily turns up [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-170).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885461/dereferencing-null-pointer-warning-in-node-generation) if you check the values returned by `malloc()` before actually *using* the pointers, the warning will go away. The answer in that post isn't accepted unfortunately.

```
int main(void)
{
    int iLength = 1024;
    int i, j;
    float *fpVec1, *fpVec2;
    fpVec1 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));
    fpVec2 = (float*)malloc(iLength * sizeof(float));

    if (fpVec1 && fpVec2) {
        for (i = 0; i < iLength;i++)
        {
            fpVec1[i] = ((float)i) + 1024.0;
            fpVec2[i] = ((float)i) * 1.7;
        }
    }
    free(fpVec1);
    free(fpVec2);
}
```